# How to make the array value comma separated

Tags: php

How can I make the values of array comma separated values?

this is my array:

```
array(
      'product_name' => 
          0 => 'pn1',
          1 => 'pn2'
      'supply_product_name' => 
          0 => 'ps1'
      'custom_product_code' => 
          0 => string 'cpc1'
)
```

how to achieve to look like these:

```
array(
      'product_name' => 'pn1, pn2' ,
      'supply_product_name' => 'ps1' ,
      'custom_product_code' => 'cpc1'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these code:

```
$arr = array(
      'product_name' => ['pn1', 'pn2'],
      'supply_product_name' => ['ps1'],
      'custom_product_code' => ['cpc1']
);

foreach($arr as $key => $val)
{
    $arr[$key] = implode($val, ',');
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: @jaybeesatulan you should accept this answer if it did helped you

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Done.